# Timer in Guizero/ TKinter

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, timer

Right now I am busy with making a GUI for my project. It also needs a test driven by time. However when I press the start button, the counter starts counting but the Gui freezes, so you cannot press the stop button. And eventually the Program stall and shut his self down.

Take a look at my code :

```
###import libaries ###
from guizero import *
import tkinter as tk
import time

timeLoop = False
###Variabelen###

Sec = 0
Min = 0
Hour = 0
test_stat = 0


###Define Loops###
def verlaat_settings():
   window2.hide()
   window3.hide()
   window4.hide()
   window.show(wait=True)

def stop_test():
   info("test_result","Test stopped at" + str(Hour) + " Hour " + str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
   text_test.value = "Test Stopped..."
   timeLoop: False



def test_loopt():
   global Sec
   global Min
   text_test.value = "Test is running....."
   timeLoop = True
   while timeLoop:
      Sec +=1
      print(str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
      time.sleep(1)
      if Sec == 60:
         Sec = 0
         Min += 1
app= App(title="Profiberry",layout="",width=480, height=272)
window3 = Window(app,title="Profiberry-Tester", layout="grid",width=480, height=272)
window3.show

###Window3###
welkom_tester= Text(window3, text="Profibus Tester",grid=[2,0,1,1])
Plaatje_profi= Picture(window3,image="logoprofi.gif",grid=[2,1,1,1])
lege_ruimte1 = Text(window3, text="", grid=[2,2,1,1])
text_test= Text(window3,text="  Waiting for input..... ",grid=[2,3,1,1])
timer_test= Text(window3,text=(""),grid=[2,4,1,1] )
lege_ruimte2 = Text(window3, text="", grid=[2,5,1,1])
lege_ruimte2 = Text(window3, text="", grid=[1,6])
Start_knop= PushButton(window3,text="Start",command=test_loopt,padx=50, pady=10, grid=[1,6] )
Start_knop.tk.config(foreground="white",background="green")
Stop_knop= PushButton(window3,text="Stop",command=stop_test,padx=50,pady=10,grid=[3,6])
Stop_knop.tk.config(foreground="white",background="red")
Exit_setting = PushButton(window3,command=verlaat_settings,text="Exit to Main Menu(F2)",padx=30,pady=10,grid=[2,6])
```

I will talk you trough this part of my program:

- Import the libraries used for this purpose.
- Give timeLoop, our while variable, a false state.
- Give our variables value.
- Below that are our Def loops `verlaat_settings` is used to move trough windows in the GUI `Stop_test` is used to preform actions when stop is pressed (also to reset the while state) `test_loopt` is the actual test, the counter has to run by here what it does in the shell.
- Below that we open the window and place the widgets.

Comment: guizero is available through `pip install guizero`

Comment: you really didn't read my question did you ?

its not Guizero its the problem that my counter Sec +=1 time.sleep(1) causes the gui to freeze but in python shell you still see the counter working

Comment: Robin46: I was providing the information to others wishing to help who did not have the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after searching for a while I found a page on here with someone on python 2.7 having the exact same problem.

the solution to this is that everything runs in the main loop and the main loop waits for ever on this `test_loopt` the solution was making a Thread, which in my case was :

```
def test_loopt():
   global Sec
   global Min
   text_test.value = "Test is running....."
   timeLoop = True
   while timeLoop:
      Sec +=1
      print(str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
      time.sleep(1)
      if Sec == 60:
         Sec = 0
         Min += 1
      if Min == 60:
         Sec = 0
         Min = 0
         Hour = 1
   if stop_test():
      timeLoop = False

def start_test_loopt_thread():
   global test_loopt_thread
   test_loopt_thread = threading.Thread(target=test_loopt)
   test_loopt_thread.deamon = True
   test_loopt_thread.start()
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is to help over users encountering a similar situation.
Although the proposed answer is imaginative, it is a bit long winded.
In GuiZero, the .display() function creates an infinite loop. Therefore, any use of normal python time functions will prevent the display loop from executing.
When using GuiZero, do not use sleep, or while loops.
It is simpler and easier to use .repeat(duration, command)
For instance the code above should work if this line:

```
Start_knop= PushButton(window3,text="Start",command=test_loopt,padx=50, pady=10, grid=[1,6] )
```

is changed into those:

```
Start_knop= PushButton(window3,text="Start",padx=50, pady=10, grid=[1,6])
Start_knop.repeat(1000, test_loopt)
```

and the original test_loopt function:

```
def test_loopt():
   global Sec
   global Min
   text_test.value = "Test is running....."
   timeLoop = True
   while timeLoop:
      Sec +=1
      print(str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
      time.sleep(1)
      if Sec == 60:
         Sec = 0
         Min += 1
      if Min == 60:
         Sec = 0
         Min = 0
         Hour = 1
      if stop_test():
         timeLoop = False
```

is modified as:

```
def test_loopt():
   global Secs, Mins, Hrs
   text_test.value = "Test is running....."
   Secs +=1
   print(str(Hrs) + " Hours " + str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
   if Secs%60 == 0:
      Secs = 0
      Mins += 1
   if Min%60 == 0:
      Secs, Mins = 0, 0
      Hrs += 1
```

If must be noted that the result is not displayed on the GUI but in the IDE and that there is no end to this loop.
It is also necessary to modify the stop_test function from:

```
def stop_test():
   info("test_result","Test stopped at" + str(Hour) + " Hour " + str(Min) + " Mins " + str(Sec) + " Sec ")
   text_test.value = "Test Stopped..."
   timeLoop: False
```

to

```
def stop_test():
   info("test_result","Test stopped at" + str(Hrs) + " Hour " + str(Mins) + " Mins " + str(Secs) + " Sec ")
   text_test.value = "Test Stopped..."
   Start_knop.after(pause_loop)

def pause_loop():
   pass
```

or something along those lines

Comment: Great first answer!

Answer (score 0):

There's a basic answer to this in [GuiZero's Documentation.](https://lawsie.github.io/guizero/blocking/) The problem is that, because of the loop, GuiZero's display loop is being blocked, like you said, stalling it and eventually crashing it. This is because GuiZero is an event-driven loop, which is why it uses the `.display()` loop to check for events.

You need to use the `.repeat` method (shown below) for the application to repeat that action.

```
.repeat( [enter delay here in milliseconds] , [command to execute] )
```

This means the loop in the function is not needed.

I understand I'm a bit late to answer this question, but I hope it helped.